# Dim screen Backlight

Tags: hp, brightness, wayland, backlight, 21.10

My laptop’s backlight is stuck, no matter what I do, the brightness controls work but nothing's clear enough as the backlight is still dim. I Have tried updating the mesa drivers ( I use a hp Elitebook 840 G2, my graphics specifications are `Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (BDW GT2)`, but updating the drivers didn't fix the problem. I use Ubuntu 21.10, but that doesn't seem to be the origin of the problem as I've had this issue since ubuntu 20.04, I have attempted using `xrandr --output <xWAYLAND0> --brightness 1.2` to increase the overall brightness, but even that didn't work and at this point I'm just hitched, none of the solutions I've seen online actually increase the backlight and i still can't see anything clearly. any assistance at this point is highly appreciated.

Comment: Backlight settings and brightness settings are not the same thing. Backlight is a hardware setting and is usually controlled with a particular key combination.  Brightness settings are completely different. If you actually are having a problem with *brightness* and not the backlight, please edit your question and describe when the problem started and describe your actions on the laptop since the last two reboots before the problem began.  Also I'm fairly certain that 8.5 is an invalid setting in xrandr.  I think 1 = 100%

Comment: You also need to enter the correct command and replace <output name> with the name of the output. Please link to the guide(s) you are following (where did you obtain these commands?). If you are entering commands that *"don't work"* - please copy/paste the **exact** commands you are running as well as the entire output of each command

Comment: @Nmath I'm referring to backlight settings alone, I've edited the question as suggested, also the outputname is not what i typed when running the command, i just copied the command as seen on the site i copied it from (that being said the question has now been edited to show my displays output name)

Comment: Run `xrandr` without any options and you will get a list of outputs.